# how to find target elements with selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I ma very new to this, but am trying to do a little web scraping with Selenium to get some reviews from trip advisor. I have something running but am running into some issues around keywords. My main issue seems to be that I am not sure what specific keywords are available to me. In my code, modified and updated for a newer version of selenium from [here](https://www.cahoover.com/technical-marketing/scraping-tripadvisor-reviews-using-python/), I have:

```
import csv
import time
from selenium import webdriver

path_to_file = './my_data.csv'


pages_to_scrape = 5

url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g186338-d7914853-Reviews-London_Bridge-London_England.html'

# import the webdriver
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get(url)

# open the file to save the review
csvFile = open(path_to_file, 'a', encoding="utf-8")
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

# change the value inside the range to save the number of reviews we're going to grab
for i in range(0, pages_to_scrape):

    # give the DOM time to load
    time.sleep(2)

    # Click the "expand review" link to reveal the entire review.
driver.find_element("path", ".//div[contains(@data-test-target, 'expand-review')]").click()


    # Now we'll ask Selenium to look for elements in the page and save them to a variable. First lets define a  container that will hold all the reviews on the page. In a moment we'll parse these and save them:
    container = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@data-reviewid]")
    
    print('got container')
    
    # Next we'll grab the date of the review:
    dates = driver.find_element("xpath", ".//div[@class='_2fxQ4TOx']")
    
    print('got dates')
```

I am hitting errors such as:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException
```

Which suggests it is struggling to find some of the keywords and buttons.

I have tried using:

```
for i in range(0, pages_to_scrape):

    # give the DOM time to load
    time.sleep(2)
    items = driver.find_elements("xpath", '//li')
    for item in items:
        print(item.text)
```

I can see the reviews in the blocks of text that this writes out but I am unable to get to them with the right keywords.

So I have two specific questions:

1. How can I retrieve the right keywords from the XML/HTML so I know what to parse?
2. Can someone unpack this line below for me a little so I get a better understanding? I tried looking in the docs but wasn't able to find clear explanations of //div.

   .//div[contains(@data-test-target, 'Read-more')]

This approach overall seemed to be the easiest example I could find but I am open to alternative/better approaches if there are some. I just need the title, date, review and data so this example did exactly what I needed.

Comment: Are you asking how to find elements on the webpage? Pleaes check https://www.browserstack.com/guide/findelement-in-selenium. Also if you inspect a page say in Chrome browser, go to Console and try $x("your xpath"); and see if it returns the right element. Then you can use in the code.